# When a structure is a mathematical structure?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

We know that a *group* or a *topology*, for example, are purely mathematical objects. But what, for example, about a *turing machine*, or a *normal-form game*? They are also structures, but one could say that they belong to computer science and ecomonics, respectively, and that they are not mathematical structures. But they all are rigorously defined using logic and sets, so, what makes them different to say that one is a mathematical object and another one not?

Comment: This question strikes me as vague, opinion-based and not very important (the map is not the territory!). Personally I would adopt "any structure about which mathematicians reason" or "any rigorously defined structure" as operational meanings of "mathematical structure". Either way, when it comes to your specific examples, I think most mathematicians would agree that Turing machines and normal-form games are mathematical structures (or if not structures, then at least mathematical objects).

Comment: All of them are mathematical objects. No difference.

Comment: Who says that a Turing machine is not a mathematical object? And besides does it matter how you label an object? Does it matter if you call it mathematical or not? Who cares? What matters is if you can do proper science with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turing machines and normal-form games are definitely mathematical structures. Although these concepts have *applications* in computer science or economics, they are also studied as abstract structures in their own right, leaving aside the limitations of any particular computer system or economy.

Many mathematical concepts start out from the consideration of physical "real world" examples, but they become mathematical structures when the essential parts of these examples are abstracted and studied independently. For instance, the whole field of probability and statistics originated from studying practical problems of calculating fair odds in gambling.